# "Коси и забивай"

Tags: сленг

Когда говорят, что человек раздумал что-то делать, то на сленге это называют "забил". А, если - о том, что он получил возможность что-то не делать (например, не идти в армию), говорят, что он "откосил". Ну и выражение "коси и забивай" тоже все знают. 
Хотелось бы узнать происхождения этих сленговых выражений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Косить,откосить - смысл "прикинулся косым"- когда-то в Армию брали только здоровых ребят, косоглазых не брали, они стрелять не могут(зрение у них снижено, плюсовые очки), а вот приходит мальчик, его папа министр, а мама владелец крупной компании, ему записывают "косоглазие, плоскостопие, сколиоз" - всё, он  "откосил" : в Армию не берут

ЗАБИТЬ - в молодёжный сленг пришло из сленга хиппи в начале 70-х, а в сленг хиппи из сленга наркоманов: забил косячок - и ничего не волнует, ничем не интересуется, живёт в своём мире.Сначала это было презрительное - "да он забил...", потом презрительное ушло, осталось только"не обращает внимания".

Есть ещё одно объяснение:развилось от выражения молодёжного сленга"Забить голову кому-то" ( разговорный ) - притупить умственные способности большим количеством ненужных сведений; отвлечь, притупить внимание. "Я забил"- у меня голова тупая, я не воспринимаю это.

Comment: По Р. И. Розиной ([ссылка](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200302006)) Слово "откосить" появилось только во 2-й половине 80-х - 90-х гг., что несколько не вяжется с версией о косоглазии (другие болезни симулировать значительно проще и эффективнее).

Comment: Почему же не вяжется? Не могу сказать, когда это появилось, может, и в 80-е, но что связано первообразно с Армией, а не с транспортом - это точно, все остальные значения вторичны. Косоглазие, плоскостопие,сколиоз считались самыми "несерьёзными"диагнозами, в лёгкой степени они есть очень у многих, слегка "подкосить" глазами можно легко, поэтому и писали эти диагнозы, что их если что, можно симулировать. Других объяснений и искать не стоит , всё и так понятно.

Comment: Проблема в том, что косоглазие, только при наличии двоения  даёт  категорию "В" (ограничено годен), если двоения нет, то вообще "Б" (годен с ограничениями), т. е. в армию косоглазых вполне себе призывают и смысла симулировать именно эту болезнь нет. Стойкий паралич двигательных мышц глазного яблока или поврежение глазных мышц симулировать проблематично.  
Не утверждаю, что моя версия верна, но с косоглазием и медкомиссией "откосить" вряд ли связан.

Comment: Ну, это смотря какая степень и какой вид - сходящееся, расходящееся. Это сейчас всех подряд берут,потому что "косят" многие.А когда-то серьёзно к набору подходили.Да речь-то не о том, а о самом значении - симулировать что-то лёгкое и побольше, прикинуться немощным,"косым", "хромым" и не пойти в Армию.

Comment: Вот поэтому время образования и важно В конце 80-х косили уже многие и с косоглазием в армию призывали. В силу пола возраста  и опыта армейской службы, я знаю немало способов "откоса", но косоглазие, не упоминалось даже как историческая. Савелий Крамер, с его косоглазием в армии служил.

Answer (score 3):

Забить в первоначальном варианте было, как верно сказано, словосочетанием. В цензурном варианте забить болт на что-л. Часто добавляли "большой и толстый". Сокращению подверглось, насколько я мог наблюдать, в речи студентов.
"Косить" и позже "откосить" родилось, опять же по личным наблюдениям, из творческого осмысления армейской прибаутки "больные, косые, хромые", давно, минимум с пятидесятых годов используемой для иронически-обобщенного обозначения контингента санчасти, особенно тех, кто, стерев ноги неумело намотанными портянками, освобожден военной медициной от нагрузок, спит в казарме, но сапог не надевает, ходит в тапочках.
Хитромудрые личности всячески затягивали заживление потертостей, чтоб подольше остаться в составе "больных, косых, хромых",  отсюда "косить" - симулировать с целью увильнуть от нагрузок.

Answer (score 2):

Коси и забивай как фразеологизм явно соединились уже после сформирования сленгового значения слов. Первоисточник вроде Николай Фоменко на Русском радио - "Серп и молот - коси и забивай".

Этимология "забивать" по всей видимости, под воздействием паронимов *забыл-забил*. Особенно чётко это слышно во фразах типа *Да забей ты на это!* - *Да забудь ты это*.

С "косить" ничего дельного не нашёл.  По всей видимости пришло от армейско-охотничьего *прицел косит* ( в смысле - прицел сбит, пуля обманом не попадает в цель). Сказалось на семантике и то, что оправдание плохой стрельбы сбитым прицелом, как правило, лишь отмазка. В итоге,  *косить* приобрело значение "обманывать, хитрить, избегая чего-либо". С этим пониманием, слово и перекочевало из  армейского сленга в "гражданский".