# Новый глагол "забивать", есть ли у него близкие синонимы из одного слова?

Tags: синонимы

> Мы делаем это, а на все остальное мы забиваем.

Найдите близкий синоним из одного слова к новому глаголу **забивать**.

Comment: Это не дубликат. По ссылке говорится об этимологии и о значении, но ничего не говорится о синонимах.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Коси и забивай"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20140/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

*Игнорировать* синоним *забивать* в широком смысле: *Я забил на свою сестру* = *Я игнорирую свою сестру*.

В более узком смысле лучше подходит *прогуливать*: *Я забил на природоведение* = *Я прогуливаю природоведение*.

Замечу, впрочем, что полного синонима в русском языке нет (потому и новое слово прижилось): *забивать* имеет помимо основного действия также характерный оттенок падения духом, прекращения борьбы: *Я забил на институт* означает, что я не только перестал ходить на занятия (*прогуливаю*) и не отвечаю на звонки из деканата (*игнорирую*), но и морально сдался, разочаровался, оставил попытки закончить образование.

Comment: Да, игнорировать по смыслу подходит. Но, мне не нравится несоответствие управления и предлогов у "игнорировать" и "забивать". Я ведь специально написал проверочную фразу с предлогом, чтобы тупо подставить под неё синоним. Так что мне больше нравится "плевать" чем игнорировать. Но у этого слово слишком яркая окраска.

Насчет полных синонимов "закрывать глаза" - идеально. Полное соответствие по предлогам и управлению. Почти полное по смыслу.

Но самое интересное -то что слова раньше не было востребовано. Ведь согласитесь очень распространенная ситуация в древней руси. Забить. А слова не было

Comment: "даем отказ на все остальное" это вообще корректная фраза? "Ставим крест"/"кладём болт"/"Закрываем глаза" это уже идиомы из двух слов. В общем, я понял что нормального синонима нет (кроме экстравагантного и не совсем точного "плевать" ). И это очень странно, ведь слово то очень востребованное во все времена.

Comment: Да, забивать у крепостных крестьян было не принято :)

Answer (score 1):

значение (1):
не обращать внимания на что-л, остаться равнодушным, не переживать по этому поводу.

значение (2):
не совершать чего-л, не идти куда-л, напр. у студентов о учебном предмете — не пойти, пропустить занятие.

пример текста:
(1) Нет нечего проще, как забить на всё. • Забить на негативы — это к добру. • Забить на все дурное и приятно провести время с друзьями. • Самый простой и верный способ забить на семью - это ее не заводить.
(2) Bовочка решил забить на уроки русского языка. • У тебя еще пять причин забить на этот экстремально опасный способ времяпрепровождения. • Мы нашли 7 отличных причин, чтобы забить на тренировки. • Символы студента — серп и молот, косить и забивать. • Ипотечники могут забить на выплату кредита? • Листовка с призывом забить на выборы.

teenslang.su/content/Забить

Comment: Ссылочку бы дали, что ли... Это словарь молодежного сленга, нет? И еще. Вопрос был о поиске односложного (в одно слово) синонима. Вы на него не ответили. Но вообще тут вы правы по сути. Бесполезно искать то, чего нет.)))

Comment: Ссылку дать не могу. Меня заблокировали. Ответы от этой учётной записи больше не принимаются. Подробнее в справочном центре.

Comment: https://teenslang.su/content/Забить

Comment: В ответ вставьте через "править". Или тоже не дает? Вообще странно, ни разу не сталкивался с подобным.